# TimeSpan.FromTicks To Milliseconds do not give expected answer

Tags: c#, timespan

I am writing some code to detect HID idle times.

```
var before = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Console.WriteLine(before);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
var after = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromTicks(after - before).Milliseconds);
```

I should get 5 milliseconds in the output, but it's not. It's pretty random. What did I do wrong?

*Note to self: I shall try system.diagnostic.stopwatch now*

Comment: Use the [`Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instead. (edit: haven't seen your comment at the end)

Comment: But why doesn't Ticks and TimeSpan work?

Comment: @Jake: You are looking at the wrong property. What you want is `TotalMilliseconds`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromTicks(after - before).TotalMilliseconds);
```

This will give you the result you want.